# How do I remove `div` in Admin area according to User Role?

Tags: magento2, phtml, admin-panel, user-roles

I am new in Magento,

Please assist on how to remove a `<div />` in a `.phtml` file according to User Role.

Comment: Hi there can you please let me know if the template PHTML file  belongs to the magento vendor/ files  ? If yes , then please share the file path , this way i will help  you write code based on the admin user role whether that div tag should show or not.Thanks